# Post photo with predefined caption using Facebook SDK 4.0.1

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am integrating facebook sdk to post image with predefined caption.

ISSUE:
I am able to post the image but I am not able to pass caption to the post.

I am using below code from the developer site.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#photos

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
    .setBitmap(image);
    .build();
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
    .addPhoto(photo)
    .build();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you may proceed with webDialog

Comment: _“to post image with predefined caption”_ – the caption has to be typed in by the user himself; you are not allowed to specify it for them.

Comment: Yes.. I go through the policy of facebook developers under control section which states that you can not prefill any caption,comment or content while posting to facebook..

Comment: If you're using ShareApi then this is a known issue, and will be fixed in upcoming releases of the SDK.